# How to color Change for Negative Values in excel sheet Using delphi programming?

Tags: excel, delphi

Using Conditional Format ?

```
oXL.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue,xlGreater,0);
oXL.FormatConditions[1].Font.color = clred;
```

Comment: You can use a custom numer format:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
oXL.Sheets['Sheet_name'].Range['A1:Z1'].FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue,xlLess,0);
oXL.Sheets['Sheet_name'].Range['A1:Z1'].FormatConditions[1].Font.Color := clRed;
```

Range of A1:Z1 is any negative values , Those are Change red colored...